# 'RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am seeing the following in my logs and my site isn't loading when I visit it. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this? `Target WSGI script '/svr/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.` `RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant`

```
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290149 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...] mod_wsgi (pid=19620): Target WSGI script '/svr/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290192 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...] mod_wsgi (pid=19620): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/svr/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290211 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290231 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...]   File "/svr/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290270 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290279 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290294 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290302 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290313 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290320 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290332 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Mon Mar 30 00:09:55.290348 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19620] [...] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

**/svr/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py**

```
"""
WSGI config for myproject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myproject.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName myproject.ca

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myproject-error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myproject-access.log combined


      WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
      WSGIDaemonProcess myproject processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/svr/myproject
      WSGIProcessGroup myproject
      WSGIScriptAlias / /svr/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

      Alias /robots.txt /svr/myproject/static/robots.txt
      Alias /favicon.ico /svr/myproject/static/favicon.ico
      Alias /static /svr/myproject/static/
      Alias /media /svr/myproject/media/

      <Directory /svr/myproject/myproject>
          <Files wsgi.py>
              Require all granted
          </Files>
      </Directory>

      <Directory /svr/myproject/static>
          Require all granted
      </Directory>

      <Directory /svr/myproject/media>
          Require all granted
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does this run locally? Typically this means you have a circular reference in your project.

Comment: @schillingt I only get this error when I deploy